# Which DB should I use in my case?

Tags: database

I would like to make a DB of our clients with max 6 columns. It could be placed on our NAS (synology) I would like max 10 users to be able to work with it in real time. There are 10k clients records and I would like my coworkers to be able to add new/delete old/make some queries etc. What kind of DB should I be using - mysql? Or maybe someone has other better idea? Thank You for Your answer.

Nobody? hmm So someone suggested sqlite, and I have done a test table with all the columns but I don't know how to solve these problems:
If splite is serverless where will I keep the DB?
If I would like my coworkers to work with the DB e.g.. add new entries/delete unwanted entries etc how will they do it on their own computers, how will they connect to the DB?
What about the interface? Should I use html to make the table etc?
Please help me to understand, thx.

Comment: Edit the title to be very specific

Comment: Thank You very much for Your hints, finally I decided to make my database in mysql and php, its almost ready, and I am learning a lot :) Greetings to everybody.

Comment: Did you press the "Accept" button too early, or is it really the best answer to your question? Changing the accepted answer is OK.

Answer (score 3):

You should do some more study on database technology.

A [database system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) acts as a black box, a mediator between the user or calling programmer and the data being managed by the DBMS. The actual data persisted to storage is never exposed to users.

So there is no need for shared file storage such as NAS. The DBMS should have its own private directly-attached storage for safety, performance, security, and simplicity/reliability.

The DBMS handles concurrency, juggling simultaneous access by multiple users. How they do that juggling varies, such as [optimistic locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) in a scheme like [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) or simple pessimistic locking. You must learn about the various approaches to learn about what works for your needs.

SQLite is meant to be an alternative to storing data in files, not intended to be a serious database server.

As for MySQL and its forks… I suggest you instead consider [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), the world’s most advanced open-source database system. But actually, for only 10 users and only 10,000 records, most any database server will do. The [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/) is another possibility.

A database server only stores your data. To access the data you either need an admin tool or you build a custom app.

There are many many admin apps out there. But doing data entry through them is a bit awkward and clumsy, similar to using a spreadsheet. Could work for very simple needs.

To build a custom app, you have a whole lot of learning ahead. Personally, I use Java with the [Vaadin Framework](http://www.Vaadin.com/) to build the user-interface as a web app. But there are many other routes.

As a beginner, I suggest you consider [FileMaker](http://www.Filemaker.com/) and [4D](http://www.4D.com/). Both have a simple data-entry and reporting facility in their own client app. And both offer an app development environment integrated with a proprietary database server. Both are relatively easy to get started with for a beginner but are also powerful enough for use by professional software developers.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite will more than suffice for a 6-column 10,000-row table with 10 simultaneous human users. It is "serverless" in the sense that it doesn't require a separate server process to access the database; you can still store the database file on a server, which indeed is what one generally does. Users can interact with the database over SSH and use the `sqlite3` command-line program or some graphical front-end.

Google Sheets would probably work fine, too. A spreadsheet isn't a database, but it doesn't sound like you need a database per se.

Comment: Asker explained why SQLite does not fit their needs. Could you please recenter your answer on Google Sheets for instance?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul The asker accepted this answer, perhaps because I answered his questions about SQLite.

Answer (score -1):

Consider [Gupta Technologies](http://www.opentext.com/what-we-do/products/specialty-technologies/opentext-gupta-development-tools-databases) (an OpenText subsidary) **SQLBase** as the dB ( v12.1 just released ) , which is a very low TCO, embedded or workgroup database, offering v. high performance and scalability. From tiny 10k rows to unlimited size. Automated mass deployment, automated installation and automated maintenance make SQLBase the database of choice for environments with limited IT support. Many driver options allow for easy integration with many 3rd Party dev tools. Or you can use Gupta's own tools SQLWindows ( TeamDeveloper v7 just released ) and be as inventive and complex, or a simple as you need. Other than TeamDeveloper , SQLBase ships with SQLTalk and SQLConsole which you can use to manipulate data either via scripts or graphically.

SQLBase also runs on Linux, which AFAIK the Synology also uses – so it should be capable of running there.

Please be aware I am not affiliated to Gupta Technologies, I have just been a technician for 30 years and like the whole toolset.

Comment: While it is OK here to recommend your own software, please note that you must [disclose your affiliation with the product](/help/promotion) – or your post will be considered spam. So please [edit] it accordingly. Apart from that: How does it fit the requirements? I very much doubt the NAS runs Windows.

Comment: I have edited as requested to clarify affiliation.  I did not mention 'Windows' in my help reply in any way. Synology run Linux on some of their products . SQLBase runs on Linux also , so thought it helpful to know.

Comment: Thanks! That OS detail should be in the answer – though with binary builds, I'm not sure if the architecture could be a show stopper (ARM vs. amd64 – I don't know what arch the Synology has). As for Windows: "Gupta's own tools SQLWindows" could be interpreted that way by those not knowing the product. // Btw: Affiliation was assumed because of your nick containing the product name ;)